# border-radius makes div higher than it should

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give pictures a really smooth shadow, that doesn't touch the pictures corners.
I tried this by giving the pictures parent div a border-radius and a box-box shadow, but now the parent div is higher than the picture.
I would also appreciate if you got a better solution for a smooth shadow.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxz2g32u/)

```css
.box {
    margin:20px;
    border-radius:20px;
    box-shadow:0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.box .box-preview {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2b/Die_landschaft_mit_den_drei_baeumen.jpg" class="box-preview">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the image is an inline element, so it is placed on a text line inside the `div`. The image is placed on the baseline of the text line, so there is some more space between the image and the bottom of the text line.

Make the image a block element to get rid of the space:

```css
.box {
    margin:20px;
    border-radius:20px;
    box-shadow:0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.box .box-preview {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2b/Die_landschaft_mit_den_drei_baeumen.jpg" class="box-preview">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/ajffyafm/

```
.box {
    margin:20px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.box .box-preview {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is doing what you want :

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4q6b9Ln/)

Here is the entire CSS :

```
.box-preview {
    margin:20px;
    border-radius:20px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    width: 100%;
    border-radius:0px; // Edit here to change the image border radius.
}
```

Comment: thants not exactly what i wanted, the shadow should be really smooth and shouldn't touch the corners. See @Guffa 's answer